# User manipulation with FOSUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

This is the action from a UserController.php controller:

```
public function createAction()
{
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->createUser();

    $user->setUsername('test');
    $user->setEmail('test@test.com');
    $user->setPassword('test');
    $user->setEnabled(1);
    $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN'));

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('crm_user_index'));
}
```

I followed the documentation but it doesn't work at all.

What's wrong ? Is this the best way to create a user from an action in a controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy have to flush the doctrine unit of work, like:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

or:

```
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```

Comment: Just an another silly question: how to apply password encryption to setPassword() ?

Comment: Rather you should use `setPlainPassword()` instead. Encoders settings are in separate layer - check `security.yml`.

Comment: Thanks again. I forgot the method name. :)